# Word (or shorter phrase for) "evaluate the relationship between"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms

I am creating a poster to describe some research I have done. Listing the objectives I have something like (edit: using more sensible comparisons):

1. Evaluate the relationship between height and weight
2. Evaluate the relationship between height and width
3. Evaluate the relationship between height and color

This is clearly not an efficient use of space, and I dislike the redundancy.

Is there a word, or shorter phrase that I can use to replace "Evaluate the relationship between"?

Comment: I'm not very clear on what is being asked in the questions. Do any of these pairs have a relationship or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: what kind of evaluation is this? a biologic/philogenetic one?

Comment: @Tony - Diane Duane's "The Book of Night with Moon" postulates a relationship between cats and snakes, actually. :-)

Comment: @SarekOfVulcan Thank you for the info. I appear to be drowning in my own ignorance!

Comment: @Tames it is biological / physiological. better examples would be height and speed, height and IQ, etc.

Comment: @TonyBalmforth the pairs have relationships, even if the examples could have been better analogues to my particular problem.

Comment: Are you aware of the [ditto](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ditto)? It's like fairy dust :)

Comment: I think this is more of a writing critique and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: If you are not asking about your actual problem, and making the question more difficult in the process (because no-one can conceive of a relationship between cats and porcupines), then it's Not A Real Question. For all we know, ***compare*** might fit the bill.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have edited the text to make more analogous comparisons. It _is_ a real question, but I decided to use familiar words so as not to detract from the point of the question, since the real words include a mix of acronyms and Greek letters that require context to understand. I do this based on the common practice at stackoverflow, which is to provide a "minimal working example".

Comment: As per the top answer right now, *no matter what* you replace the phrase with, the redundancy will still be there, and space will still be wasted. The solution is all about typography, not vocabulary.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA [top answer right now](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77000/10942) uses eight fewer words, reducing the count from 29 to 21. That doesn't seem like a purley typographical solution.

Comment: @Abe: it reduces the word count *not* by answering your question as stated and providing a single word for "evaluate the relationship between", but by ignoring your question and instead pulling that string out of each bullet. That *is* a purely typographical solution.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend simply:

> Evaluate the relationships between:
>   - cats and dogs
>   - cats and snakes
>   - cats and porcupines

Answer (score 6):

As for you comment, what you are evaluating is called **[correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)** (e.g. the older a person is, the higher the iq result in one test), this is a specific type of relation between variables in a statistical test. So, possibly you could substitue "evaluate the relationship between" for "test correlation between (x and y, y and z, etc)". You could say "test correlation between x, y and z", in this way it would comprise all the tests between variables

Answer (score 3):

I'm don't know of a briefer term for that phrase; you may find it expedient to start out with "Let *X* stand for evaluating the relationship between two items", and then go on with your list of "*X* P and Q" elements.  Suitable choices for *X* are thick on the ground: for example, *[reconcile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reconcile)*, which ordinarily means "To make things compatible or consistent" may suit, as more figuratively may one of *[orthogonalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthogonalization)*, *[orthonormalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthonormalize)*, *fix, rationalize, rebasis, convolve, stratify*.  Or, format the list as an explanation followed by bare "P, Q" elements.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rephrase: “Examining dog-cat interactions” etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing certain aspects of behavoir, function, utility, etc. between these pairs of animals, the term **analogy** (noun) or **analogous** (adjective) may be appropriate, especially if the structures that leads to those characteristics are different.

Answer (score 1):

*Compare and contrast* height and weight?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may have to explain the kind of relationship you are trying to demonstrate here. For the current example, I could simplify it into one sentence as:

> Evaluate the relationships between height, and each of weight, width
>   and color.